# MVC Ajax Int32 error

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, jquery

Hi when I try to do an Ajax post to my controller I keep getting this message:

> The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult
>   GetContactsByDepartment(Int32)' in
>   'Intranet.Controllers.MyController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter.

The method head looks like this: public JsonResult GetContactsByDepartment(int id)

What am I missing? I have ensured that the id is being passed through my Jquery ajax call.

Comment: Paste in your AJAX code too please, if you aren't passing in a value for id, then int32 (which cannot be null) will throw such an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename id to for example DepartmentID. 
Probably an issue with your registered routes.

Comment: figured it out. I needed to do /id at the end of the URL I was trying to pass them like you would to a web service in .net webforms